# How do I stop list comprehension once i get an item above certain condition limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I need a small clarification of how to approach it. I have a list 'm', and i'm iterating through to find an integer above a certain limit, say '90'.
I want to stop iterating once this limit is achieved **and post the item**(that is meeting the condition).
For example, if 98.877 is the item, i have to append it to a new list(see below snippet).

**Problem**

My challenge is that I get to extend only the item the comes before the item that meets the condition. I'd appreciate your help.

```
m = [('a', 0.6720430254936218), ('a', 0.9672043025493621), ('a', 0.6720430254936218), ('a', 0.6720430254936218), ('a', 0.8720430254936218), ('a', 0.6720430254936218), ('a', 0.6720430254936218), ('c', 0.6720430254936218), ('c', 0.6720430254936218), ('c', 0.6720430254936218), ('c', 0.6720430254936218), ('o', 0.6720430254936218), ('o', 0.6720430254936218), ('o', 0.6720430254936218), ('o', 0.7720430254936218), ('o', 0.6720430254936218), ('r', 0.6720430254936218), ('r', 0.6720430254936218), ('r', 0.9720430254936218), ('r', 0.6720430254936218), ('d', 0.6720430254936218), ('i', 0.6720430254936218), ('i', 0.6720430254936218), ('i', 0.6720430254936218), ('n', 0.6720430254936218), ('n', 0.6720430254936218), ('n', 0.6720430254936218),]

simis = []
def end_of_loop():
    raise StopIteration

simis.extend(list(end_of_loop() if item[1]*100 >= 90 else item[1]*100 for item in m))

print(simis)
```

Comment: This is almost certainly an XY problem

Comment: If you want to reach all the items that larger than 90 then `new_list = [item[1] for item in m if item[1]>=90]`.

Comment: Note that ``itertools.takewhile`` is a cleaner replacement for manually crashing the iteration with ``end_of_loop``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, that's a generator expression, not a list-comprehension.
Regardless, it seems like you just want to find- and append the first item that satisfies a condition, so you'd just use `next`:

```
simis.append(next(item for item in m if item[1]*100 >= 90)[1]*100)
```